# admob does not show up in android

Tags: android, admob

I'm a beginner,I'm trying to set an admob add in my app.But I have some errors witch I can't manage.

**XmlFile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest File.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admob"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
  android:allowBackup="true"  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"      android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
android:name="com.example.admob.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"             
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|scre enSize|smallestScreenSize" />

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

**Java Code:**

```
package com.example.admob;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private static final String MY_AD_UNIT_ID = null;
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
main.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);             
adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");
}

 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
 adView.destroy();
 super.onDestroy();
 }
}
```

when Activity start this type error occur `onFailedToReceivedAd(InvalidAdRequest)`.

I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading the `AdRequest` which has the test devices registered. Change your code to:

```
//....
main.addView(adView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);             
adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: it does not help man :/, i'm getting crazy, i don't know what to do @Jong

Answer (score 0):

In your relativelayout that contains the adview, are you appending the content layout after the adview. If so, what are the android:layout_width and android:layout_height values. If you are using fill_parent/match_parent for both, then your adview will never show.

The trick is to change the relativelayout to the linearlayout. Then for the content layout within this linearlayout, set its android:layout_width="fill_parent" and android:layout_height="0dp". Add a new attribute android:layout_weight="1" for the content layout. What these does is to ask the content layout to accomodate the remaining space of linearlayout after the adview has occupied its place. Hope this helps.